# Global variable as default argument

Tags: c++, include

```
//header.h
void foo(int a = some_global_variable);

//file1.cpp
int some_global_variable = 2;
void foo(int a){}

//file2.cpp
#include "header.h"
foo();
```

I get error on compilation some_global_variable undeclared identifier (header.h),
which makes sense since `some_global_variable` is defined in `file1.cpp`.Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: I tried `extern some_global_variable` in `header.h`.Compiler did not complain.Is this the right way to go?

Comment: When were default arguments added to C language? If you are talking about C++, please don't spam with C language tag.

Comment: You know that in C++ you must *declare* all symbols before they are used? Have you tried that? To *declare* the variable before the declaration of the function?

Comment: how about adding "some_global_variable" in the header file as static int?

Comment: @user1118094 Using `static int` in header file creates independent `some_global_variable`s in each included translation unit making the variable non-global! Using `extern` in the header is the way to go.

Comment: I am curious as to why you want to use a variable as a default function argument? This seems like a nightmare bug in the making.

Comment: @JustinFinnerty `some_global_variable` is actually a data structure which will be updated by `foo()`.`foo()` should work with `some_global_variable` most of the times.But some times i want to update a different data structure which i will pass to `foo`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to know of the existence (but **not** the value) of `some_global_variable` at the point of encountering it as a default argument.

To that end, using `extern` *would* work. Then its definition could reside in a different compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

You proably want this:

**header.h**

```
extern int some_global_variable;   // <<<<<<<<<<<<< add this line
void foo(int a = some_global_variable);
```

If you add `extern int some_global_variable;`, the compiler knows that there is a variable called `some_global_variable` somewhere, otherwise it wouldn't know what `some_global_variable` is.

**file1.cpp**

```
int some_global_variable = 2;
void foo(int a) {}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

Comment: Note that the definition of `foo` doesn't have to be in in the same translation unit as the definition of `some_global_variable`.